# Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I work in a spring project which uses mysql db. When every insert and update sql command runs in backend side of the project while the app is running in my local,  i got these type exceptions for "datetime" variables;

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'CREATION_DATE' at row 1
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(ServerPreparedStatement.java:665)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
>       ... 54 more

Mysql version: 5.7.18, mysql-connector-java version: -5.1.38, user-timezone is"-Duser.timezone=Europe/Istanbul" in tomcat 7 vm arguments and db timezone: GMT +3

Sample code block;

```
        ResponseCreateTicket response = new ResponseCreateTicket();
        TicketDTO ticket=new TicketDTO();
ticket.setTicketNumber(UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
        ticket.setStatus(TicketStatus.UNCOMPLETED.toString());
        Date date = new Date();
        ticket.setCreatedOn(date);
        ticket.setReferenceNumber(request.getReferenceNumber());
        getTicketDAO().createTicket(ticket);
        response.setTicketNumber(ticket.getTicketNumber());
        return response;
```

The sql hibernate showed and binded parameters;

> Hibernate: insert into eis_ticket (TICKET_NUMBER, STATUS, CREATED_BY, CREATION_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, REFERENCE_NUMBER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   2018-05-16 10:57:37 TRACE BasicBinder:? - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - 9BF25A08-C442-45FA-A95F-8E59502CE037
>   2018-05-16 10:57:37 TRACE BasicBinder:? - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - UNCOMPLETED
>   2018-05-16 10:57:37 TRACE BasicBinder:? - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - 
>   **2018-05-16 10:57:37 TRACE BasicBinder:? - binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - Wed May 16 10:57:32 EEST 2018**
>   2018-05-16 10:57:37 TRACE BasicBinder:? - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - 
>   2018-05-16 10:57:37 TRACE BasicBinder:? - binding parameter [6] as [TIMESTAMP] - 
>   2018-05-16 10:57:37 TRACE BasicBinder:? - binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - b4be9b87-21c4-4001-b80d-244420ab2e00
>   2018-05-16 10:57:37 TRACE BasicBinder:? - binding parameter [8] as [BIGINT] - 1925
>   2018-05-16 10:57:37 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:? - Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'CREATION_DATE' at row 1

The date format can be change to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" but there is hundreds of these types codes in project so it will not be the right solution.  What could be causing this problem? Mysql connector is updated but not worked.

Comment: You’re gonna have to show some code. The datetime value appears to be empty from the stacktrace.

Comment: The error indicates an empty string passed to a datetime column. You need to pass a `null` value, not an empty string, but you really *should not* pass strings to datetime columns at all. Use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

Comment: The question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

If the column type is date-time, you can easily modify the column and set the default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, this will ensure that every record inserted will default to the current server date and time. However if you are generating the timestamp manually, then the data type generated on the app, is not similar to the data type used when inserting in the database
You can use this to modify the column default, then leave the creation_type column `NULL` when inserting a record.

ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;

Comment: This problem not occur just creation date, it occurs every datetime types. If column types changed to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, what will we do when recording different time?